# SDL_Surface::pixels changes it's value

Tags: c++, sdl

Examining the implementation of SDL_LockSurface function I stumbled upon this:

```
/* This needs to be done here in case pixels changes value */
surface->pixels = (Uint8 *)surface->pixels + surface->offset;
```

Why would `pixels` change its value? Could it be, that the location of the actual pixel array also changes?

Particularly, consider this:

```
SDL_LockSurface(sur);
Uint8* my_pixels = reinterpret_cast<Uint8*>sur->pixels;
SDL_UnlockSurface(sur);
```

Now, is it safe to assume that `my_pixels` will always point to the pixel array of the surface, that `sur` points to currently, unless I free it? (I'm almost sure it is, since moving those huge arrays around seems a bit stupid, but still... maybe I'm stupid...)

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not safe to assume.

"moving those huge arrays" doesn't involve actually copying any data.  What changes is not the physical address where the data is placed (which may even be in GPU RAM) but the virtual->physical mapping.

Comment: Is it safe for software surfaces?

Comment: @nnnn: Read [the documentation for `SDL_LockSurface`](http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdllocksurface.html), which is very clear that "Not all surfaces require locking. If `SDL_MUSTLOCK(surface)` evaluates to 0, then you can read and write to the surface at any time, and the pixel format of the surface will not change."

Comment: hmmm... I read and was pretty comfortable with that, until now. If the `pixels` can change, then the `offset` should as well, since it's participating in recovery of correct `pixels` value, which means that `SDL_MUSTLOCK` may behave differently, for the same surface: evaluate to false, if the `pixels` wasn't changed, and to true, if it was. 
I guess I'm just not supposed to read the implementation... but I want to get a better understanding.